# URLs in sitemap not allowed in Google search console

Tags: google-search-console

I have a new website for which I setup Google Analytics, Google Search Console and Bing Webmaster Tools. These were setup last week Wednesday (5 days ago at time of writing).

I submitted the sitemap to Bing Webmaster Tools and Google Search Console. Bing works perfectly and is happy with the sitemap.

Google search console sais `Sitemap can be read, but has errors` and then goes on to say `This url is not allowed for a Sitemap at this location.` Here's a screenshot:

[image]

My sitemap is at the root, ie: `www.example.com/sitemap.xml`. Here it is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/pricing/</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/contact/</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/faq/</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

When setting up Google Search Console you can select `Domain Verification` or `URL prefix`. I selected `Domain Verification`. However since getting the above error I also tried `URL prefix` which results in the same issue.

I only have 4 urls on the website and so I went to `URL inspection` and requested indexing for each of them manually. The next day I came back to check and they are all now indexed correctly.

Please note that I do have a `robots.txt` in place as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

So it appears as though my site and all urls are indexed correctly, it is just the sitemap that search console is complaining about. As mentioned, Bing webmaster tools is happy with the sitemap and I am confident it does not contain errors because it is generated automatically by my backend.

Do I need to be worried about this or can it be safely ignored? I'm not sure what else I can do since my domain verified correctly and the urls I submitted manually are now indexed?

Comment: Does your sitemap start with the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`?  Is that missing, or did you just not copy and paste it in?

Comment: Yes it does start with that. Sorry for not including it, I have updated the question now to include it.

Comment: What type of property do you have verified in Google Search Console?  Do you have the domain property, or do you have a prefix property.   If it is a prefix property, what is the prefix?

Comment: On a side note, you should remove the `changefreq` and `priority` fields from your sitemap.  Google doesn't use them.  They just make the file unnecessarily large.

Comment: Ok I'll remove the `changefreq` and `priority`. I have the domain property because I also have sub domains however those are not in the sitemap and I have not added them to search console. I have `example.com` and `support.example.com` which is why I registered the domain property for `example.com`. But as mentioned my sitemap only contains the above listed urls for `example.com`

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then.   I thought maybe you had submitted this sitemap on a prefix property without the `www` or with `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: Ok I'll keep trying things. This is very strange since Bing webmaster tools is happy with the sitemap. Google search console is complaining about the sitemap and a missing robots.txt even though both are present and correct.

Comment: Can you share a link to your site so that we can double check it?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://www.feederloop.com

Comment: Looks good to me, so I'm not sure what Google is complaining about.   With only 4 pages on your site and good navigation on-site between those pages, you don't actually need an XML sitemap.    See [Myth: An XML sitemap is needed for SEO; it helps rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/xml-sitemap-rankings/)  At best, XML sitemaps help get a large number of pages crawled and give you extra stats in Google Search Console.  With only 4 pages, you don't actually need those benefits.

Comment: Thanks very much for all you help. Fortunately the typo caught by MrWhite was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the domain of the sitemap URLs.

Your canonical hostname is `www.feederloop.com`, but you are using `www.feederlop.com` (one `o`) in your sitemap URLs, which is indeed invalid.

Comment: Good catch, MrWhite.